# web3 python - AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'abi'

Tags: web3js, python

I am trying to use an example ABI but its not being found.

My problem is on last line:

```
AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'abi'


infura_url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxx'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
required_abi = web3.eth.abi.encodeEventSignature('Transfer(address,address,uint256)')
token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=token1_address, abi=required_abi)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a call to `Web3.keccak` instead.

The error shows up because the relavant Python modules do not have any function named `encodeEventSignature`. This is a npm module (JavaScript) function.

Python code:

```
from web3 import Web3
Web3.keccak(text="Transfer(address,address,uint256)").hex()
```

Node.JS code:

```
const abi = require("web3-eth-abi")
abi.encodeEventSignature('Transfer(address,address,uint256)')
```

Both produce the same result: hex string that looks like `0xddf2...b3ef`.

Comment: Added a last line that isn't fitting.  Can you resolve please?

Comment: @BAR one question per post, please!